# Mapstruct Mapper Error : Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I had existing mapper in code. I am trying to modify it.

Line Before Mapping is as follow. I was directly mapping id to id.

```
@Mapping(target = "id", source = "source.id")
public TargetDto toTargetDto(IpEntity source);
```

Updated the mapping as follow. I needed to add mapping based on function because I am reading some flag and setting it up.

```
@Mapping(target = "id", expression = "java(getIdDtoBasedOnFlag(source))")
public TargetDto toTargetDto(IpEntity source);
```

Method I added is as follows.

```
default IdDto getIdDtoBasedOnFlag(IpEntity src) {
    IdDto cd = new IdDto();
    if(idType.equalsIgnoreCase("standard")){
        StndIdRelationEntity c = src.getPrimaryId();
        cd.setIdCode(c.getIdNumber());
        cd.setId(c.getId().toString());
        cd.setIdName(c.getIdName());
    }
    else{
        IdRelationEntity c = src.getId();
        cd.setIdCode(c.getSourceCode());
        cd.setId(c.getId().toString());
        cd.setIdName(c.getIdName());
    }
    return cd;
}
```

Now I am getting error in Impl class that gets generated as

```
  java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable source
  location: class com.package.mapper.MapperImpl
```

IdDto class is as follows.

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class IdDto {
    @JsonProperty(value = "id")
    private String idId;

    @JsonProperty(value = "display")
    private String idName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "idCode")
    private String idCode;

    private Map<String, String> links;
}
```

If check the line in Impl class

```
    protected IdDto idRelationEntityToIdDto(IdRelationEntity idRelationEntity) {
        if ( idRelationEntity == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        IdDto IdDto = new IdDto();
        IdDto.setIdName( idRelationEntity.getIdName() );
        IdDto.setId( getIdIdBasedOnFlag(source) );//Error is coming from this line
        return IdDto;
    }


sPLTargetDto.setId( idRelationEntityToIdDto( source.getId() ) );
```

As you can see source is not getting passed properly in generated Impl method, Because of which it is failing. How do I fix it.

I tried adding using qualifiedName but it didn't work.

```
@Mapping(target = "Id", expression = "java(getIdDtoBasedOnFlag(source))",qualifiedByName="getIdDtoBasedOnFlag")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `expression` is useless in your case, you can simply use `qualifiedByName` like this:

```
@Mapping(target = "id", source = "source", qualifiedByName = "getIdDtoBasedOnFlag")
public TargetDto toTargetDto(IpEntity source);

@Named("getIdDtoBasedOnFlag")
default IdDto getIdDtoBasedOnFlag(IpEntity src) {
  // ...
}
```